# Iterating Google analytics API function on a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-python-client

I have a Dataframe (f) of inputs: Page Title (title_), Start date ('date_') and End date (date_date), and I want to iterate The Google analytics API get_report function on every row in the DataFrame, to get a new DataFrame of the results.

Here is my Code:

```
for i in f.index:
    lista = []
    df = print_response(get_report(
             config.service,  
             start_date=[f.loc[i]['date_']],
             end_date=[f.loc[i]['date_date']], 
             view_id='xxxxxxxx',
             metrics=[{'expression': 'ga:pageViews'}],
             dimensionFilterClauses= [{
                      "filters": [{
                              "dimensionName": "ga:pageTitle",
                              "expressions": [f.loc[i]['title_']]}]
              }],
             dimensions=[{"name": "ga:pageTitle"}]))
    lista.append(df)
    time.sleep(2)
print(lista)
```

I get the error:

> TypeError: Object of type 'date' is not JSON serializable

What is wrong with my code, and how to structure the output as a DataFrame?

[update] That's my get_report function:

```
def get_report(analytics, start_date, end_date, view_id, metrics, dimensions, dimensionFilterClauses):
  return analytics.reports().batchGet(
      body={
        "reportRequests":[
        {
                "viewId": view_id,
                "dateRanges":[{"startDate":start_date,"endDate":end_date}],
                "metrics":metrics,
                "dimensions": dimensions,
                "dimensionFilterClauses": dimensionFilterClauses,
        }]
      }).execute()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried following the [quick start](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-py)

```
def print_response(response):
  """Parses and prints the Analytics Reporting API V4 response.

  Args:
    response: An Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
  """
  for report in response.get('reports', []):
    columnHeader = report.get('columnHeader', {})
    dimensionHeaders = columnHeader.get('dimensions', [])
    metricHeaders = columnHeader.get('metricHeader', {}).get('metricHeaderEntries', [])

    for row in report.get('data', {}).get('rows', []):
      dimensions = row.get('dimensions', [])
      dateRangeValues = row.get('metrics', [])

      for header, dimension in zip(dimensionHeaders, dimensions):
        print header + ': ' + dimension

      for i, values in enumerate(dateRangeValues):
        print 'Date range: ' + str(i)
        for metricHeader, value in zip(metricHeaders, values.get('values')):
          print metricHeader.get('name') + ': ' + value
```

Comment: Great. This solves the output issue, but not the input one. I mean "Object of type 'date' is not JSON serializable" Error.

Comment: Hence the follow the quick start the report object is quite complex you appear to be supplying something as a date object when it should be a string.   Its hard to know what you are doing when we cant see get_report() method

Comment: Update: I did it. Solved after converting the date object to a string. Thanks